# broken links and styles on form post to mysql, is it because of mysql_real_escape_string?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string, broken-links

in order to keep safe was told to

use mysql_real_escape_string before sending to Mysql if i'd be displayed

well i do:

```
....

   $b = mysql_real_escape_string($b);
   $r_int = mysql_real_escape_string($r_int);
   $r_ext= mysql_real_escape_string($r_ext);

   $id_tmp = $_SESSION['id'];
   $insert = "INSERT INTO table (nombre, coment, iduser,fecha)
                           VALUES ('$b','$r_int','$id_tmp',NOW())";
....
```

But if those values contained any `<a href="where">go</a>` it will turn into `<a href="\where\">go</a>`

and.. i can't go! haha,

how can i solve this and keep safe?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stripslashes function of PHP

```
echo stripslashes($string);
```

takes out the slashes and displays it like it was originally

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you might have `magic_quotes_gpc` or one of its ilk turned on. Older PHP versions auto-escaped everything, so by doing `mysql_real_escape_string()` (as you should be), you actually added another layer of escaping.

The proper solution is to turn off the [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc). They're deprecated and SHOULD be off, and you keep on using `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

NOTE: Turning off magic_quotes has to be done from php.ini, or via a php_value in httpd.conf/.htaccess. You can't do it from an in-script ini_set(), because by the time that ini_set executes, PHP's already done the magic quoting.

Comment: The other answer was easier for me, but thanks for writing. might be usefull in future!